# Laravel eloquent limit results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a working query:

```
Object::all()->with(['reviews' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('approved', 1);
        }])
```

And I want to limit the number of reviews, per object, that is returned. If I use:

```
Object::all()->with(['reviews' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('approved', 1)->take(1);
        }])
```

or

```
Object::all()->with(['reviews' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('approved', 1)->limit(1);
        }])
```

it limits the total number of reviews, where **I want to limit the reviews that are returned by each object**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: so you want to get top 1 reviews from all object?

Comment: Exactly that. Not 1 in total, 1 review per object.

Comment: I feel like your query would work if your re-arranged it a bit: `$objects = Object::with(["reviews" => function($query){ $query->where("approved", "=", 1)->limit(1)->get(); }])->get();` I think `Object::all()->with([...]);` might be affecting it, but I'm not 100% sure on this.

Comment: I created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score 3):

> Eloquent way

Make one relationship like below in your model class

```
 public function reviews() {
       return $this->hasMany( 'Reviews' );
    } 

  //you can pass parameters to make limit dynamic
  public function firstReviews() {
        return $this->reviews()->limit( 3 );
    }
```

Then call

```
Object::with('firstReviews')->get();
```

> Faster way(if you just need one review)

Make a derived table to get the latest review 1st and then join it.

```
Object->select('*')
      ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT object_id, reviews  FROM reviews WHERE approved=1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,1
        as TMP'), function ($join) {
            $join->on ( 'TMP.object_id', '=', 'object.id' );
        })
      ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there an `eloquent` way to achieve this, using Laravel's functions?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This works fine as long as you query for exactly one *Object* - as you start doing something like `Object::with('firstReview')->all()` (querying for more than one *Object*), the limit applies to the sum of all *Reviews*, no longer giving you 3 (in your example) **per Object**. Check the answer by @user3158900 for a (unfortunately also not universal) solution when retrieving more than one record at a time.

Answer (score 2):

### Grabbing 1 child per parent

You can create a helper relation to handle this very easily...

In your `Object` model

```
public function approvedReview()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Review::class)->where('approved', 1);
}
```

Then you just use that instead of your other relation.

```
Object::with('approvedReview')->get();
```

### Grabbing n children per parent

If you need more than 1, things start to become quite a bit more complex.  I'm adapting the code found at https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/ for this question and using it in a trait as opposed to a `BaseModel`.

I created a new folder `app/Traits` and added a new file to this folder `NPerGroup.php`

```
namespace App\Traits;

use DB;

trait NPerGroup
{

    public function scopeNPerGroup($query, $group, $n = 10)
    {
        // queried table
        $table = ($this->getTable());

        // initialize MySQL variables inline
        $query->from( DB::raw("(SELECT @rank:=0, @group:=0) as vars, {$table}") );

        // if no columns already selected, let's select *
        if ( ! $query->getQuery()->columns)
        {
            $query->select("{$table}.*");
        }

        // make sure column aliases are unique
        $groupAlias = 'group_'.md5(time());
        $rankAlias  = 'rank_'.md5(time());

        // apply mysql variables
        $query->addSelect(DB::raw(
            "@rank := IF(@group = {$group}, @rank+1, 1) as {$rankAlias}, @group := {$group} as {$groupAlias}"
        ));

        // make sure first order clause is the group order
        $query->getQuery()->orders = (array) $query->getQuery()->orders;
        array_unshift($query->getQuery()->orders, ['column' => $group, 'direction' => 'asc']);

        // prepare subquery
        $subQuery = $query->toSql();

        // prepare new main base Query\Builder
        $newBase = $this->newQuery()
            ->from(DB::raw("({$subQuery}) as {$table}"))
            ->mergeBindings($query->getQuery())
            ->where($rankAlias, '<=', $n)
            ->getQuery();

        // replace underlying builder to get rid of previous clauses
        $query->setQuery($newBase);
    }
}
```

In your `Object` model, import the trait `use App\Traits\NPerGroup;` and don't forget to add `use NPerGroup` right under your class declaration.

Now you'd want to setup a relationship function to use the trait.

```
public function latestReviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class)->latest()->nPerGroup('object_id', 3);
}
```

Now you can use it just like any other relationship and it will load up the 3 latest reviews for each object.

```
Object::with('latestReviews')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The actual issue is limiting the number of reviews per Object. By using this helper, can I achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, note the `hasOne`.  That removes the need to add a limit.  You just need to be careful because if there are multiple related reviews that are approved, it would grab the first one in the table.

Comment: Excellent. What if I'd like to limit it to 3 reviews per object (or any number, for example)? There won't be any multiple related reviews, each review `belongsTo` an `Object`

Comment: That becomes a little more difficult I think.  There is a very good blog post about it.  https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Comment: I just walked through this to make sure it was still working as expected.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but I get this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::latestReviews()`.

Comment: That means you didn't add the `latestReviews` function to your model.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did add it to my model prior to this error.