# Eloquent hasOne and a big table, doesn't limit in the query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, performance, eloquent

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `weathers` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_district` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_county` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_freg` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_max` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_min` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressure` decimal(9,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `humidity` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `weathers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `current_weathers_id_district_index` (`id_district`),
  ADD KEY `current_weathers_id_county_index` (`id_county`),
  ADD KEY `current_weathers_id_freg_index` (`id_freg`);

ALTER TABLE `weathers`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

This table has more than 4M rows, and I can select the current weather (last inserted row) for a district, county, or freg (small local).

Doing the following query, e.g:

```
select * from `weathers` where `weathers`.`id_county` in (?) order by `id` desc [197]
```

which is applied by the relation in `County` Model:

```
public function current_weather() {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Weather::class, 'id_county')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
```

All rows belong to a county, district or freg, all rows have null on two of these. Ex: if I'm looking for rows where `id_county = 197` these rows have `NULL` on `id_district` and `id_freg` columns.

Well the main problem is that `hasOne` should limit by 1 in the query itself, this should be implicit, or am I wrong?

Since It's not like this, I am having major performance issues, doing a query like this for e.g 10 counties is a 10+ secs wait, just because the relation `hasOne` isn't limiting the results on the query itself.

Note: Using Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 2):

`hasOne()` is not the correct relation to be used in this context. To get the weathers for a county, you would define a `hasMany()` relation to get all weathers for this county. Then you would additionally define a scope on the weather model to only get the latest entry.

```
public function scopeCurrent($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1);
}
```

When you then want to get the current weather of a county, you would go this way:

```
$currentWeather = $county->weather()->current()->first();
```

The important difference to see when designing your relation is, that the relation is between a county and a weather. Not between a county and a single item of the weather table.

Comment: Thank you sir, and how would I eager load this? Sorry for the 'bonus' question

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and see "Constraining Eager Loads". You can use the same query builder options that I used for defining the scope on eager loading constraints.

Comment: I already tried that: `County::with(['weathers' => function($q){$q->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(1);}])->findOrfail(request()->id);`, but limits the total rows, not the rows for object (County), faced this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283076/laravel-eloquent-limit-results

Comment: You should do what the top answer says on the question that you linked. Define a helper relation. That should do the job